# Command line tools to replace bytes in a file

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, binary

I need to write a script that patches a few bytes at a particular offset in a binary file. I know of textual tools for this task (sed, though I find it utterly hard to use) but can't find one for binary patching. Are there any?

If not installed by default, anything I can install with Homebrew would be acceptable as well.

Comment: Perl maybe? Supports seek() etc.

Comment: Yeah, Perl is even worse than sed for me :)  But if you can supply a working perl command where I specify file path, offset and bytes to write, then you'll have a winner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve it with `dd` command. Here's an example:

```
$ hexdump StringComparison  | head -1
0000000 cf fa ed fe 07 00 00 01 03 00 00 80 02 00 00 00

$ printf '\x11\x11\x11' | dd of=StringComparison bs=1 seek=4 count=3 conv=notrunc
3+0 records in
3+0 records out
3 bytes transferred in 0.000293 secs (10238 bytes/sec)

$ hexdump StringComparison  | head -1
0000000 cf fa ed fe 11 11 11 01 03 00 00 80 02 00 00 00
```

Explanation:

- of = input file
- bs = block size
- seek = position (offset)
- notrunc = do not truncate the output.

Comment: Smart! And I now remember I even used `dd` a few years back for similar tasks.